# How to add a route to Amazon VPC into an instance's OpenVPN connection?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I want to setup a render farm in EC2 (all Win2012r2) with several slaves an one instance with a OpenVPN connection to our office LAN (all OSX).

What I have done so far:

- setup VPC `10.42.0.0/16`
- setup OpenVPN `10.8.0.0/24`, one instance as client, the server is in our office `192.168.1.0/24`, the connection is working flawlessly
- added `10.8.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24` to the VPC Route Tables/Routes Tab with target: VPN client instance
- `Source/dest checks` turned off for the VPN client instance

What is working:

- I can ping around in the VPC
- I can ping around the VPN

What doesn't work:

- ping from VPN server to the clients VPC-address
- ping from a slave node to the VPN net

some debugging:

- wireshark on the VPN client `10.8.0.14` shows a ping echo 'no response' when trying to `ping 10.8.0.14` from `10.42.243.30`, so the return route seems to be broken

So how do get the VPC working that every instance can ping to the VPN server and additionally our office lan?

Regards,
Dennis

Comment: So, the OpenVPN client (inside the VPC) is on Windows?  Don't you need to do... something... to enable routing or, perhaps more precisely, forwarding of routed packets, between IP interfaces on a Windows server?  I stay as far away from them as possible, and have for many years, but perhaps you need something comparable to http://www.itgeared.com/articles/1066-how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-on-windows/ (from an older version of Windows Server) or something involving "Routing and Remote Access" configuration?

Comment: I usually stay away from it, too. Well, now there is no chance to avoid Windows. As shown in your link I already set the key to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to configure your Network ACLs (Security Groups) to allow all inbound and outbound traffic between your VPC nodes.

[image: ACLs]

Comment: Thanks Rico, the in- and outbound ACLs look exactly like shown in your screenshot. Do you have any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the Windows service `Routing and Remote Access` didn't run as suspected.

No everything works like a charm!

--Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Please check your VPN Settings from OpenVpn Admin Page. Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access at *Rooting* section from the *VPN Settings* Tab on *OpenVPN Admin Page*.

[image]